# Magento 1.9 Add Random Fee to Order Totals?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have wrote and modified a module **Add fee payment** at random magento
The following script

1. Config.xml

   ```
          <sales>
               <quote>
                   <totals>
                       <fee>
                           <class>payment_fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                           <renderer>payment_fee/checkout_totals_fee</renderer>
                           <admin_renderer>payment_fee/adminhtml_sales_order_create_totals_fee</admin_renderer>
                           <after>customerbalance,discount,freeshipping,msrp,nominal,shipping,subtotal,tax,tax_shipping,tax_subtotal,weee</after>
                           <before>grand_total</before>
                       </fee>
                   </totals>
               </quote>
          </sales>
   ```
2. Model/Fee.php

.

```
public function getFee(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) { 
            $helper = Mage::helper('payment_fee'); 
            $quote   = $address->getQuote();
            $method  = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
            $fee     = 100;
            $tofee   = 1000; 

            $rand    = (rand($fee,$tofee));

            $feeType = $helper->getFeeType();
            if ($feeType == Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract::HANDLING_TYPE_FIXED) {
                return $rand;
            } 
        }
```

3. Model/Sales/Qoute/Address/Total/Fee.php

.

```
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
            parent::collect($address);
            $this->_setAmount(0);
            $this->_setBaseAmount(0);
            $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);

            if (!count($items)) {
                return $this;
            }

            /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
            $quote = $address->getQuote();
            /* @var $feeModel Brander_PaymentFee_Model_Fee */
            $feeModel = Mage::getModel('payment_fee/fee');
            if ($feeModel->canApply($address)) {
                $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
                $fee          = $feeModel->getFee($address);       
                $balance      = $fee - $exist_amount;
                $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
                $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);
                $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);

                $operator = Mage::helper('payment_fee')->getFeeOperator();
                if ($operator == 0) {
                    # code...
                    $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
                } else {
                    $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $address->getFeeAmount());
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }
 public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        $amount = Mage::helper('payment_fee')->getFee();
        $paymentMethod = $address->getQuote()->getPayment();

        if ($amount != 0 && $address->getAddressType() == 'shipping' && is_object($paymentMethod)) {    // billing & shipping address
            $title = Mage::getModel('payment_fee/fee')->getTotalTitle(null, $address->getQuote());

            try {
                $methodCode = $paymentMethod->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
            } catch(\Exception $e) {
                return $this;
            }

            if (!isset($amount[$methodCode])) {
                return $this;
            }

            $address->addTotal(
                array(
                    'code' => $this->getCode(),
                    'title' => $amount[$methodCode]['description'], 
                    'value' => $address->getFeeAmount()
                )
            );
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Question : 
Why not synchronous random results between Onepage checkout with that in Magento admin page sales?

In Onepage Checkout

[image]

In Admin page Sales

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Check your "Banyak Diskon" charges make diffrence in total.

Comment: @dhiren-vasoya why grandtotal in different random ?

Comment: you used $rand    = (rand($fee,$tofee)); in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone my module in github. FIX Module

https://github.com/tobidsn/paymentrandomfee

Answer (score 0):

This is because the fees that you are calculating in the checkout are re-calculated when you create the order.
Sp your random function will certainly give a different result for both of them.
If you want to have a consistent value between the two of them, I would rewrite a little your getFee function and store the value in session:

Start by checking if the random value is stored in the checkout session. If that's the case, then your value is this one.
If you don't have the value stored in the checkout session, then generate your random value, and save it in session. Then return the value.

Something like that :

```
public function getFee(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) { 
        $helper = Mage::helper('payment_fee'); 
        $quote   = $address->getQuote();
        $method  = $quote->getPayment()->getMethod();
        $fee     = 100;
        $tofee   = 1000; 

        $rand = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getRandomFee();
        if(!$rand){
            $rand    = (rand($fee,$tofee));
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setRandomFee($rand);
        }

        $feeType = $helper->getFeeType();
        if ($feeType == Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract::HANDLING_TYPE_FIXED) {
            return $rand;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks hellimac, how remove random session in new order? if the order again will show the same random numbers,

Comment: You could set the random fee to null on the success page, or in the success action of the checkout controller

Comment: You're welcome. Please validate the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Ok, but I still have not been able to create an API that will be used on Android Ecommerce